# WordPress generating empty files for certain image_size's

Tags: wordpress, debugging

Running into a weird situation where WordPress generates all the proper files for the various image sizes, however is generating an empty file for two of the bigger image_sizes. [Here's a screenshot of the files that are being created.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lsh7ee0dtj7bva/Screenshot%202014-05-22%2011.38.58.png) You can see that the two highlighted files in that screenshot have a file size of zero.

Here's the WordPress code for my image_sizes:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size(380, 280, true);
add_image_size( 'ms-feature-downsized', 1260, 700, true); 
add_image_size( 'ms-feature', 2000, 1111, true); // creating empty file
add_image_size( 'ms-cover', 2000, 3000, false); // creating empty file
```

**This is unique to this installation.** I've tested the same theme and images locally, with the same plugins, and the images get properly created.

The server WordPress is running on has the following setup:

- PHP Version 5.4.28
- memory_limit: 256M
- upload_max_filesize: 64M
- imagick module version:  3.1.0RC2
- ImageMagick version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-8 2012-05-02 Q16
- GD Support: enabled
- GD Version: bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

Any thoughts on why these image sizes are being created as empty files?

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately will not necessarily solve your problem but its helpful and worth knowing.

For all the crop sizes specified in your theme that are larger than that of the image size being uploaded, WordPress will skip over these and not process them.

This applies for both width and height, the image being uploaded must be both as tall and as wide as the specified crop sizes to be processed and cropped. Any smaller than your specified crop sizes and it wont be cropped.

Logical - crop is there to make the image smaller, not to stretch and make it bigger.

In the case that WordPress does not process and crop this image because it is smaller than the set crop size and you are calling it in your theme or plugin, WordPress will return the original image uploaded as a fallback.

Hope this helps you or someone else at some point...